# Spring Boot test Filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-test

NOTE: the errors below were actually caused by a typo in the filter, see @jccampanero mentions in his answer below

I've been trying a couple different approaches to testing a Filter however I'm continuously getting one error or another so I'm hoping for some direction.

Here's a dummy Filter that should just do a redirect.

```java
package org.example.filters;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class RedirectFilter implements Filter {
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) req;
    chain.sendRedirect("/splash");
  }
}
```

And a basic Spring Boot Application class:

```java
package org.example;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationClass {

}
```

I think I'm just not clear on what 'level' of Spring Boot Test I'm trying to do, here's some attempts I've done and the errors:

Option 1. Trying with mocks, for example from [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-test/src/test/java/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/samples/standalone/FilterTests.java)

```java
package org.example.filters;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.redirectedUrl;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

public class LocaleFilterIntegrationTestStandalone {

  @Test
  public void whenNoLocaleRedirectToSplash() throws Exception {
    standaloneSetup(new TestController()).addFilters(new RedirectFilter()).build().perform(get("/"))
        .andExpect(status().isFound()).andExpect(redirectedUrl("/splash"));
  }

  @Controller
  private static class TestController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String get() {
      return "got it";
    }
  }
}
```

Error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest cannot be cast to class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse`

Option 2, try using `@WebMvcTest`, which has the same issue as Option 1

```java
package org.example.filters;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.redirectedUrl;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@WebMvcTest
public class LocaleFilterIntegrationTestWebMvc {
  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mvc;

  @Test
  public void noLanguageShouldRedirectToSplash() throws Exception {
    mvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().isFound()).andExpect(redirectedUrl("/splash"));
  }

  @Controller
  private static class TestController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String get() {
      return "got it";
    }
  }
}
```

Error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest cannot be cast to class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse`

Option 3, try booting the whole context, which I think is required to be able to cast to `HttpServletRequest`:

```java
package org.example.filters;

import java.net.URI;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class LocaleFilterIntegrationTest {
  @LocalServerPort
  private int port;

  @Autowired
  private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Test
  public void noLanguageShouldRedirectToSplash() throws Exception {
    URI uri = new URI("http", "localhost:" + port, "/", null, null);
    String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri.toString(), String.class);
    // not sure how, but test for redirect...
  }

  @Controller
  private static class TestController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String get() {
      return "got it";
    }
  }
}
```

Error: `class org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade cannot be cast to class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse`

Option 4, suggested by @m-deinem

```java
package org.example.filters;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse;

public class LocaleFilterIntegrationTestPlain {
  private final RedirectFilter redirectFilter = new RedirectFilter();

  @Test
  public void noLanguageShouldRedirectToSplash() throws Exception {
    MockHttpServletRequest req = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    MockHttpServletResponse res = new MockHttpServletResponse();
    MockFilterChain chain = new MockFilterChain();
    redirectFilter.doFilter(req, res, chain);
  }
}
```

Error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest cannot be cast to class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse`

Comment: You cannot do a `sendRedirect` on a `FilterChain` ... Maybe you could use `GenericFilterBean` instead of a plain servlet `Filter`?

Comment: @DirkDeyne so your recommendation is to, for example, implement `OncePerRequestFilter` instead of just `Filter`. Are there other ways to get a real `HttpServletRequest` available in the test?

Comment: Just create an instance of the filter, use the mock classes and check the result. You are making all your tests for this filter overly complex.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First your `RedirectFilter` contains an error it tries to cast the incoming `HttpServletRequest` to a `HttpServletResponse` as you are using the wrong variable.

```java
@Component
public class RedirectFilter implements Filter {
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    res.sendRedirect("/splash");
  }
}
```

Both lines use `req` whereas the latter should use `res` (which is also what the exception is quite literally telling you).

Next just write a simple unit test, you are making things overly complex by trying to write integration tests.

```java
public class RedirectFilterTest

  private final RedirectFilter filter = new RedirectFilter();

  @Test
  public void redirectTest() {
    MockHttpServletRequest req = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    MockHttpServletResponse res = new MockHttpServletResponse();
    MockFilterChain chain = new MockFilterChain();
 
    filter.doFilter(req, res, chain);

    assertEquals("/splash", res.getRedirectedUrl());
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work, I still get `java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest cannot be cast to class javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse`

Comment: Very nice implementation @M. Deinum

Comment: Well ofcourse not, you cannot cast a Request to a Response, which is an error in your own code. `HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) req;
` that line is just wrong, as it casts the request to a response. You sloppy pasted the previous line and changed the casts and not the parameter to use (use `res` instead of `req`).

Comment: I modified the answer to include this.

Answer (score 1):

Please, maybe it is just a typo, but be aware that in your `RedirectFilter` `doFilter` method you are incorrectly casting the variable `req` to `HttpServletResponse`:

```java
package org.example.filters;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class RedirectFilter implements Filter {
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    // Please, note the incorrect cast
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) req;
    chain.sendRedirect("/splash");
  }
}
```

Instead, it should be:

```java
package org.example.filters;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class RedirectFilter implements Filter {
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    chain.sendRedirect("/splash");
  }
}
```

It can be very likely the reason of the `ClassCastException` and the failing tests.

Once solved, the solution proposed by @M. Deinum is a very good and straightforward one.

Comment: Wooooow, yup that was it. Well, thanks for being so eagle eyed!

Comment: You are welcome @errorline1. I am happy to see that you solved the problem.